# What should I research about before getting a puppy?

Tags: dogs, puppy

I'm thinking about investing into a puppy, only I do not know much about them and  I don't know where to start in my research. Which are the crucial topics I need to research on? What books and sources will be helpful for my research?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! I understand that you are focused on a puppy in this stadium of your decision, but you need to research for a grown up dog too ;) because the puppy WILL grow, and you do not want to give he/she away then

Comment: Please don't do mistake that I did. Adopt a puppy if you: 1. Will be dedicated to your pup(specially 1st year, sometimes it becomes real frustration if training is not going well but your love for dog must not stop you), 2. Your every member of family should be loving puppies(This was my mistake) 3. Family members should cooperate with you in training(This might be weird tip but believe me very important) 4. Get in contact with person who raised his/her dog for asking questions. 5. Amd every dog is unique. Follow up the answers it's great.

Comment: Hi, I marked your question as duplicate. If you feel like the linked question and the answers therin don't answer your question, please leave me a comment and point out which aspect isn't answered. We can then reopen your question and clarify the missing details.